# Creating DIR works half the time

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# When a match is not found, just present nothing.
shopt -s nullglob

# Match all .wav files containing the date format.
files=(*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.wav)

if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "No match found."
fi

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  # We get the date part by part
  file_date=''
  # Sleep it to parts.
  IFS="-." read -ra parts <<< "$file"
  for t in "${parts[@]}"; do
    # Break from the loop if a match is found
    if [[ $t == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
      file_date=$t
      break
    fi
  done
  # If a value was not assigned, then show an error message and continue to the next file.
  if [[ -z $file_date ]]; then
    echo "Unable to find date string in $file."
    continue
  fi

  file_year=${file_date:0:4}
  file_month=${file_date:4:2}

  mkdir -p "$file_year/$file_month"

  # -- is just there to not interpret filenames starting with - as options.
  mv  "$file" "$file_year/$file_month"
done
```

When I run this code for this type of files `OUT340-20130529-153516-1369856116.1254989.wav  q1064-20130508-234158-1368070917.885627.wav` ...etc half of it works for example... for all files with the year and month 201306.....wav it creates the DIR 2013 and the month DIR 06 perfect and any month higher than 06... but if I have a file with a month below 06 for example  201305 it creates a DIR 201305 instead of DIR 2013 and then DIR 05 .. it moves the file correct. Help please.

```
more files....
OUT398-20130624-151423-1372101263.1793982.wav  q1200-20130628-212505-1372469104.1866114.wav
OUT398-20130624-151530-1372101330.1793991.wav  q1200-20130628-213046-1372469445.1866233.wav
OUT398-20130624-151820-1372101500.1794016.wav  q1200-20130629-120812-1372522091.1882860.wav
OUT398-20130624-152213-1372101733.1794045.wav  q1200-20130629-200936-1372550975.1895662.wav
OUT398-20130624-152442-1372101881.1794067.wav  q1200-20130629-225834-1372561113.1900285.wav
OUT398-20130624-152921-1372102161.1794079.wav  q1200-20130629-233440-1372563279.1901149.wav
OUT398-20130624-153535-1372102535.1794097.wav  q1200-20130629-235905-1372564744.1901865.wav
OUT398-20130624-153941-1372102781.1794112.wav  q1200-20130630-005644-1372568202.1902811.wav
OUT398-20130624-154551-1372103151.1794129.wav  q1200-20130630-010445-1372568684.1902846.wav
OUT398-20130624-155246-1372103566.1794159.wav  q1200-20130630-185852-1372633131.1926286.wav
OUT398-20130625-120223-1372176143.1808796.wav  q1200-20130630-194016-1372635615.1927485.wav
OUT398-20130625-120541-1372176341.1808803.wav  q1200-20130630-214058-1372642857.1930370.wav

OUT398-20130508-131952-1368033592.879814.wav   q1200-20130525-045719-1369472238.1165178.wav
OUT398-20130508-132411-1368033851.879856.wav   q1200-20130525-180457-1369519496.1177104.wav
OUT398-20130508-132604-1368033964.879859.wav   q1200-20130527-022816-1369636094.1212356.wav
OUT398-20130508-132735-1368034055.879867.wav   q1200-20130528-052751-1369733270.1238938.wav
OUT398-20130508-132937-1368034177.879871.wav   q1200-20130528-212945-1369790984.1246272.wav
OUT398-20130508-133627-1368034587.879886.wav   q1200-20130529-001535-1369800934.1248760.wav
OUT398-20130508-133841-1368034721.879890.wav   q1200-20130529-020008-1369807207.1249977.wav
OUT398-20130508-134227-1368034947.879900.wav   q1200-20130529-043239-1369816358.1251628.wav
OUT398-20130508-134412-1368035052.879904.wav   q1200-20130529-212332-1369877011.1259076.wav
OUT398-20130508-134850-1368035330.879930.wav   q1200-20130530-033837-1369899516.1263701.wav
OUT398-20130508-135101-1368035461.879940.wav   q1200-20130530-053741-1369906660.1264667.wav
OUT398-20130508-135334-1368035614.879954.wav   q1200-20130530-054224-1369906943.1264679.wav
OUT398-20130508-135543-1368035743.879962.wav   q1200-20130530-190816-1369955295.1270565.wav
OUT398-20130508-135756-1368035876.879966.wav   q1200-20130530-201623-1369959382.1272134.wav
OUT398-20130508-135945-1368035985.879972.wav   q1200-20130531-054907-1369993746.1279860.wav
OUT398-20130508-140155-1368036115.879988.wav   q1200-20130531-183331-1370039610.1286278.wav
OUT398-20130508-140706-1368036426.880020.wav   q1200-20130531-192717-1370042835.1287645.wav
OUT398-20130508-141859-1368037139.880068.wav   q1200-20130531-195250-1370044368.1288042.wav
OUT398-20130508-142116-1368037276.880072.wav   q1200-20130531-211655-1370049413.1290684.wav
OUT398-20130508-142240-1368037360.880099.wav   q1200-20130531-212413-1370049852.1290854.wav
OUT398-20130508-142459-1368037499.880108.wav   q1200-20130531-230851-1370056129.1293922.wav
```

Comment: What do you see when you run the code under `bash -x yourscript`?  On the face of it, what you say is happening should not happen.  Which platform are you on, and which version of `bash` are you using? Your script should probably exit if there are no files found.  Hmmm...your May file contains 1369856116; that matches the 8-digit number; your file should be vanishing into 1369/85 sub-directory (did they have WAV files in the Middle Ages?).  And shouldn't that `==` be `=~`?

Comment: 1369856116 doesn't match an 8-digit number and 20130529 goes before it but you are right, the script should be debugged with `bash -x`.

Comment: Related to @JonathanLeffler's comment, are you sure that the date is the *first* 8-digit number in *every* file name?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Even so what's odd is that   `file_year=${file_date:0:4}` could only have 4 characters but it created a 6-character directory instead.

Comment: Since the regex does not include `^` and `$`, I think that a 9-digit number does match the regex for an 8 digit number, if it is applied as a regex.  I'm not wholly convinced about any of this — the `=~` vs `==` alone is suspicious.

Comment: @konsolebox Good point. Obviously we're missing some info; as you said, only 4-character directory names should be created (at the top level).

Comment: …However, some testing (as opposed to opining from the experience of Bourne shell vintage 1985) indicates the `[[` manages to interpret the regex even with `==`…and the `break` after the match should stop 1369856116 from being used at all…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `==` matches only 8-digit strings. See the part about `==` inside double brackets in the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: There are so many special cases associated with the `[[` operator that it is very messy to learn — especially if you learned to program shell 30 years ago when there weren't special cases like `[[`.  There is a lot of power to consistency — and `[[` is inconsistent with the rest of the shell parsing.  None of which is to dispute your observations.  …And, like mbratch, I've run the test code on the test files without any problems…

Comment: I ran your script as shown on two file examples you show and it worked OK for me.

Comment: If you try and throw more files than just 2 it might not because when I do like 10 files it works fine but when i get to 100 or so with all different years and months it starts acting like like I stated above

Comment: Generate a list of the minimum number of file names that can cause it to go wrong.  Simplify your life; put an `echo` in front of the `mv` so that you can rerun the script many times without changing your directory at all.  Then paste the minimum list of file names you managed to come up with into the question so we can see what you're facing.  What is different about the one iteration that goes haywire compared with the others that don't when you run under `bash -x`?  You have looked at that, haven't you?

Comment: This is my first script so no i havent

Comment: added more files .. one DIR which worked fine and another one that didnt

Comment: I think there's something you're not telling us here. I ran your script with the updated list of files you gave, and the files were moved into the directories `2013/05` and `2013/06` as expected. Are you sure the directory `201305` wasn't created by an earlier version of your script? Run `ls -dl 201305` to find out when the directory was last modified.

Comment: is it creating one DIR called 201305 or is it 2013 and then inside that 05 and it was edited when I ran the script above.

Comment: So later today I will the script on a fresh backup with at least 1000 files and ill redirect any errors into a file then ill repliy

Comment: @Ryan It could actually help if we could see the error log file. And have you verified that the directories created (`YYYYMM` and not `YYYY/MM`) were not made before the script has become stable? As you can see the problem is hardly on the script so looking at the script won't really help. If there are other causes it could be `bash` itself, or perhaps `mkdir`. Maybe you need to upgrade either to newer or more stable versions.